# One-one chat application in flex using lccs

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air, lccs

I tried my hands on Adobe LCCS and created a simple text chat application using lccs components.I succeeded in creating the chat application,I followed the sample from this link [check here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=289).

This application works fine if its a group chat where all the users who have opened this app can see the messages and can respond.My requirement is to create one like skype or gtalk where the user can select the member and can chat with that person alone.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: It is working but i want to chat to a particular person in the room,if i send a message, all the members of the room are able to see it.I want to send the message to a particular person in the room.

Comment: @Flextras,I will explain with an example.consider there are 3 persons in the room (say A,B,C).If A sends a message both B and C can see.what i want here is if A selects B and send a message only B should be able to see it.Hope its clear now.

Comment: @Flextras,I have shared the code in my original question.thats why i have added that link there.I think you failed to notice the link.I tried that sample and i did not change anything there.I asked what steps should i follow to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using subtopics on your messaging component?  This would allow you to use the same destination as your chat application, but give you the flexibility to message specific people.  The main chat would use the destination without a subtopic, then you could select a person, create a subtopic using their userid (thus making the interaction identification unique), and send your messages.  The person recieving the message would then filter out the messages from their registered subtopic (they would need to always register their userid as a subtopic consumer) by the userid of the person sending the message.

Answer (score 0):

HI, within the LCCS it is impossible, you need to create Flex chat application by using Shared object and use Wowza in the backeed(as a media server).

I apply this technique to accomplish requirements.

Comment: hey can you send me some sample code,it ll be of great help to me,bcos i dont know what Wowza is,so please send some sample code.Thanks for replying...

Comment: yes sure but where i can send you sample chat application code.

Comment: You can send here itself,otherwise send it to my gmail id that is availble in my profile